# "No changes found" occurs while pushing to SVN server through TortoiseHg with hgsubversion

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I've setup a SVN Server by using the VisualSVN Server, and have the TortoiseSVN, TortoiseHg, hgsubversion installed in my development PC. I can successfully CLONE the SVN repo from the SVN Server, and COMMIT changes using TortoiseHg. However, when I want to PUSH back the changes onto the SVN Server, I always get the following message:

```
pushing to svn+https://SVN.DEVTEAM:8443/svn/ProjectX/
searching for changes
no changes found
[command completed successfully Wed Dec 22 14:32:31 2010]
```

I've the following lines in my Mercurial global settings:

```
[extensions]
rebase=
hgsubversion = C:\hgsubversion\hgsubversion
```

Please advise!

Thanks,
William

Comment: Can you see your additional changesets in Hg? Are they on the head you're currently trying to push back to SVN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that, this case happens as we didn't perform any SVN commits prior pulling/pushing through Mercurial. My workaround is asking the SVN Server admin to do an initial commit to the SVN repo after the repo was created on the server.

Make sure that the initial commit includes at least one file as containing only folders is not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah-ha! Solved the problem for me as well. Thank you for putting this question & answer here where I could find it.

Comment: Thanks for this! A small addendum -- I tried adding and deleting a folder in VisualSVN to do an initial 'commit', but that wasn't good enough ... you actually have to have a file present in the repository for Mercurial to download when doing the clone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the message appeared, because the changeset to push was not the working copy parent.

The situation:

- 3 repos: svn-server, central-hg (with hgsubversion) and a hg-working-clone
- central-hg is synchronized with svn (pull)
- the working clone has one new revision
- the working clone pushes to central-hg
- the central tries to push to svn

Result: no changes found

After "hg update tip" in central repo (where tip was the new revision), the push to svn works again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just edited the .hg/svn/rev_map to fix the svn rev to the hg changeset.

Comment: Could you help me with how to do this, id there any documentation of what the syntax for that file is?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing in a similar situation, was add a file to the svn using svn as suggested by William Choi. Then I cloned the svn using hibernate again to a different directory and transplanted the changes I had made to that one (using the transplant extension). This resulted in me being able to commit the transplanted changes to svn.